# Google Map pin not centering when inside a Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, dictionary, modal-dialog

I have a Google Map that is embedded in a Bootstrap modal on this site...

http://designbyparent.co.uk/agilita

The modal is launched using the location icon in the left hand sticky menu.

My problem is when the modal is launched, the map pin is positioned off screen in the top left of its containing col-md-6 div.

I've looked at many other similar issues on here and elsewhere on the web, the solution to which has mainly consisted of resetting the map size and center using some variation of map.setCenter, however, this has not worked for me.

It's as if the map is looking for the center of the screen and not the div. Is there anything else that could detect the center of the containing div?

Here is the code for the modal...

```
<div id="mapModal" class="modal" data-backdrop="static" and data-keyboard="false">
<div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
    <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content fadeInUpBig row">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <span class="close">&times;</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="modal-center">
                    <div class="menu-btn fadeInUp delay-200"><p>Agilita Ltd</p></div>
                    <div class="menu-btn fadeInUp delay-300"><p>Chancery LanE</p></div>
                    <div class="menu-btn fadeInUp delay-400"><p>London</p></div>
                    <div class="menu-btn fadeInUp delay-500"><p>EC4A 1BL</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6"> 
                <div class="mapContainer" style="display:block;width:100%;height:100%;">
                <style>
                  #map { width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: grey; }
                  .map-control { display: none; }
                  #map .map-control { display: block; }
                </style>

                <div id="style-selector-control"  class="map-control">
                    <select id="style-selector" class="selector-control">
                        <option value="silver">Silver</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="map"></div>
                <script>
                  function initMap() {
                    var uluru = {lat: 51.5143894, lng: -0.1127558};
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                      zoom: 16,
                      center: uluru,
                      scrollwheel: false,
                      disableDefaultUI: true
                    });
                    var iconBase = 'http://designbyparent.co.uk/agilita/wp-content/themes/shapely/assets/icons/';
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: uluru,
                      map: map,
                      icon: iconBase + 'aPin.png'
                    });
                    var styleSelector = document.getElementById('style-selector');
                    map.setOptions({styles: styles[styleSelector.value]});
                  }
                  var styles = {
                    silver: [
                      {
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#f5f5f5"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "elementType": "labels.icon",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "visibility": "off"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#616161"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#f5f5f5"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#bdbdbd"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "poi",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#eeeeee"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "poi",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#757575"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "poi.park",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#e5e5e5"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "poi.park",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#9e9e9e"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "road",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#ffffff"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "road.arterial",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#757575"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "road.highway",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#dadada"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "road.highway",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#616161"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "road.local",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#9e9e9e"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "transit.line",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#e5e5e5"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "transit.station",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#eeeeee"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "water",
                        "elementType": "geometry",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#c9c9c9"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "featureType": "water",
                        "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                        "stylers": [
                          {
                            "color": "#9e9e9e"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                };

                features.forEach(function(feature) {
                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: feature.position,
                    icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
                    map: map
                  });
                });



        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(51.5143894, -0.1127558));

            </script>
            <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBoToNMoas8ad5FPpYETmBKpa-z6u1uBrE&callback=initMap">
            </script>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!---->   
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="bottom-menu">           
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactModal" class="rotating_button">
                        <img src="http://designbyparent.co.uk/agilita/wp-content/themes/shapely/assets/icons/Phone_solo.svg" class="rotate_icon aw"/>
                    </a>
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mailModal" class="rotating_button">
                        <img src="http://designbyparent.co.uk/agilita/wp-content/themes/shapely/assets/icons/Email_solo.svg" class="rotate_icon aw"/>
                    </a>
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mapModal" class="rotating_button">
                        <img src="http://designbyparent.co.uk/agilita/wp-content/themes/shapely/assets/icons/Location_solo.svg" class="rotate_icon aw"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```